# Refused to set unsafe header

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth-2.0, httprequest

it logs

Refused to set unsafe header “Host”
Refused to set unsafe header “Access-Control-Request-Headers”
Refused to set unsafe header “Origin”

From what I've found from looking around is that Host, Origin,Access-Control-Request-Headers are automatically set by the browser for security reasons as mentioned in [w3 headers](https://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader%28%29-method)

Is there a way to send the proper header information without resulting in these errors?

Comment: The only header you need set from Angular is `Authorization`. The rest (except for `Access-Control-Request-Headers` which is a server response header) are set by the client and not configurable

Comment: Also, `success()` and `error()` are [deprecated](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice)

Comment: If I remove Origin from the header, it says Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not set in the response header and I can't read the response I get back from the server

Comment: How are you loading your app? It's not going to work via the `file:///` protocol. You'll need an HTTP server like [Express](http://expressjs.com/)

Comment: Actually, looking at the error, it seems the remote API may not be set up for CORS access.

Comment: When I pass Origin as a header, it doesn't log that error

Comment: But it does log the *"Refused to set unsafe header “Origin”"* error, right?